# Android studio 4.0.1 run button not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-4.0

After pressing run button or debug button the button disabled but `gradle` not starting.
[image]

Also Android studio `throws an exception`

```
com.crashlytics.tools.bootstrap.BootstrapException: Exception starting OSGi bundle: com.crashlytics.tools.intellij.core
```

I have tried

1. clean
2. rebuild
3. Invalidate and restart
4. Restart pc

Result is the same.

Comment: I had the same issue this morning, looks like its a BUG

Comment: I found a solution and post it. see below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps the result is come from idea files.

- Manually delete `.idea` folder
- sync project with gradle files
- clean
- rebuild